# Why my event.target isn't working?

Tags: javascript

Why my event.target isn't working?

ok please help me to find the issue, my html is

```
<input type="text">
```

my css is

```
.bg {
  background-color:#777;
  outline:none;
  border:solid 2px tomato;
}
```

and my js,

```
const input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'INPUT') {
    input.className = "bg";
  } else {
    input.className = "";
  }   
});
```

Now once i click the input element the "bg" class name is adding, however, why it isn't removing, when i click on outside of input element?

Comment: Look at the `blur` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to accomplish this using Javascript then you should use the focus and blur events together.

Here is the code. This way when the input element loses focus the class can be removed.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');

function inputBGHandler(e) {
  if (e.type === "focus") {
    input.className = "bg";
} else {
  input.className = "";
}
}

input.addEventListener('focus', inputBGHandler);
input.addEventListener('blur', inputBGHandler);
```

```css
.bg {
  background-color:#777;
  outline:none;
  border:solid 2px tomato;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Thank you @canolyb1. learn a new event usage, and exactly achieved what I want to do. By using it i don't need any parent div. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

thats because you are adding a click event listener to `input` object, so `e.target.tagName`  is always `"INPUT"`, if you add the event listener to `document/body`, it will work. But,

**try instead use css pseudo selector `:focus` , adding events is not at all required for your purpose**

```
input:focus {
  background-color:#777;
  outline:none;
  border:solid 2px tomato;
}
```

Comment: i just want to do it with Js for my learning. Yes it's changing, i put input inside a div parent and add the eventListener on it, it's changing now. Thank You.